# Using SSML with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, ssml

I'm trying to use speech API to read aloud a text. I would want to insert a pause in the sentence but I've been unable to do it. I've been trying to use SSML as the text:

```js
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Hello <break> World";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

But it reads it as it was plain text (reading the marks, etc.) I've also tried this kind of strings:

```js
msg.text = '<speak>Hello <break time="2000ms"/> World </speak>'
msg.text = '<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="string"></speak>'
```

But it didn't worked. There is [an onMark property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/onmark) on SpeechSynthesisUtterance that suggest that it should be possible to use SSML, but I haven't found anything about that.

Do you know if it's possible to use SSML and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSML still isn't implemented:
https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/10
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88072

The final comment on the first thread seems to say that they still have no ideaa how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that everything is ready but they need a flag to know where the text is SSML. It shouldn't be very difficult, but...